# Agile classes for the developer

Tags: agile

Where can I find good agile classes for developers?

Not really talking about scrum and estimating user stories here.

More along the lines of principles from the gang of four... patterns and object orientated code.

Preferably somewhere around the New York and Boston area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Object Mentor. They have very developer focussed classes.
http://www.objectmentor.com/omTraining/omi_training_index.html